# Indexing the name of a function in a for loop in Julia

Tags: function, loops, for-loop, julia

I'm trying to write a for loop to generate multiple functions. I would like to iterate on the name of the functions as well but I can't seem to make it work. Here's what I want to do:

```
for i = 1:n
    h_[i](x) = i*x
end
```

I know this doesn't work but I would like something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @laborg mentioned, quite often [you don't need/want to use metaprogramming](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-warn-new-users-away-from-metaprogramming/35022). Since you already try to use array indexing syntax (`h_[i]`) perhaps you should simply create a vector of functions, for example like so:

`h_ = [x->i*x for i in 1:n]`

Here, `x->i*x` is an [anonymous function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions-1) - a function that we don't care to give a name. Afterwards you can use actual array indexing to access these different functions and call them.

Demo:

```
julia> n = 3;

julia> h_ = [x->i*x for i in 1:n];

julia> h_[1](3)
3

julia> h_[2](3)
6

julia> h_[3](3)
9
```

No metaprogramming involved.

(On a side note, in this particular example a single function `h(x;i) = i*x` with a keyword argument `i` would probably the best choice. But I assume this is a simplified example.)

Comment: Great thank you, works perfectly! And indeed, it was a simplified function, what I have uses a vector indexed by i inside the function, so there is no way around it.

Comment: If you think that either my or @laborg's reponse have answered your question you might want to consider indicating so by making it the accepted answer. This makes it easier for people to see which questions don't have a satisfactory answer yet and need attention. Also both you and the answerer will be awared a few points here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You have to evaluate the name of your function:

```
for i = 1:n
    f = Symbol(:h_,i)
    @eval $f(x) = $i*x
end
```

More on this:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/

As a general note on meta programming in Julia: It really helps to think twice if meta programming is the best solution, especially as Julia offers a lot of other cool features, e.g. *multiple dispatch*.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, it works great but I can't seem to find a way to call each indexed function after that. I ended up using crstnbr's solution to circumvent this problem.